# How do I use a string as a variable in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

This is what my cells look like:

[image]

This is my code, I'll explain it below.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim product as String
Dim group as Long
Dim recordno as Long
dim pol_number as Long
dim plan_name as Long

product = "corp"
group = 1
recordno = 1
pol_number = 1
plan_name = "TTT"

Range("A2").Select
For i = 1 to 5
    ActiveCell.Value = Selection.End(xlUp).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select
Next i

End Sub
```

I want to fill in all of the cells with the variable values. I understand that variables are not case sensitive, and I understand that the code I have will just fill the cell with the text in the upmost cell of the column, but I don't know if there is a function that would take the text of the top cell and convert it to a variable. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do - you never reference the variable. You select column A and set it to itself, so it's PRODUCT. You need to reference `product`

Comment: You know that `Dir` is going to try to locate a file or folder by that name on your file system? What the heck are you trying to do?

Comment: VBA variables aren't case-sensitive. Can you try to explain what you want to do again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do something like

```
someCell.Value = someOtherCell.Value
```

and `someOtherCell.Value` is `"product"` then `someCell` won't be filled with what you have saved in the variable `product` but with `"product"` (I included the quotation marks to emphasize that's it's a string). That's a good thing because otherwise it would mess your code up if you accidentally put in the name of some random variable in your code.

If your requirements are like this:

- You have values for PRODUCT etc that you write to write in the row below PRODUCT etc.
- The headers are not always in the same order.
- You might want to add new variables later on without too much fuss.

Them some kind of keyed list might be what your looking for. That means that rather than referencing the variable by a numerical index, you can reference them using names.

If the order is fixed, you might be better of just using an array where item 1 is the product name, item 2 is the group number etc, like ja72 and Sgdva suggested.

However, if you still want to reference the variables by name, you could use a collection:

```
Dim coll As New Collection
With coll
    .Add "corp", "product"
    .Add 1, "group"
    .Add 1, "recordno"
    '...
End With
```

Then instead of selecting cells and referencing `ActiveCell` you should reference the cells directly (using selections and ActiveCell can be avoided most of the times and slows down the macro and can even cause unnecessary errors)

```
For i = 1 To 5
    Cells(2, i).value = coll(Cells(1, i).value)
Next i
```

An alternative to a collection is a dictionary which offers an easy way to check if a key exists (with a collection you have to catch the error)

```
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
With dict
    .Add "product", "corp"
    .Add "group", 1
    .Add "recordno", 1
    '...
End With
```

Now you can check if the entry exists first so it won't throw an error:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    If dict.Exists(LCase(Cells(1, i).value)) Then 'note that the dictionary keys are case sensitive
        Cells(2, i).value = dict(LCase(Cells(1, i).value))
    Else
        MsgBox "Entry for " & LCase(Cells(1, i).value) & " not found!"
    End If
Next i
```

Note that when you use `dict("somekey")` and the entry `"somekey"` doesn't exist, it won't throw an error but add an empty entry.

Comment: The variable values change, and when they change they get written to a new row. The code that you gave at the end could work for that. But I just want to look through all of the columns and put, in the current row, the new value of the variable that corresponds to the column header.

Comment: @JamesMarriott Then you can use the first example I gave and loop through the columns? I see that you edited your code and will adapt my answer when I get the chance.

Comment: I've never been aware of collections. It isn't quite as easy as a variable, at least since I would have to go back and replace all of my variables. But if this is the only way, I like your solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JamesMarriot You should check out dictionaries as well, they can be very handy. I think its the easiest way to do exactly what you asked but it might be overkill for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to go from variables to cells

```
Dim values as Variant   
'Array 0 to 4
values = Array(product,group,recordno,pol_number,plan_name)    
Range("A2").Resize(1,5).Value2 = values
```

The reverse is

```
Dim values as Variant
'Array 1 to 5
values = Range("A2").Resize(1,5).Value2 
product = values(1,1)
group = values(1,2)
recordno = values(1,3)
pol_number = values(1,4)
plan_name = values(1,5)
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Arrays, so I am researching that now. Is it possible to put an array in an array? Otherwise, this is a great idea but won't work for what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes in VBA arrays can contain variants which means can contain other arrays. In fact the array returned by the `Range().Resize().Value2` statement is a 2D array, or an array of arrays

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Why not an array and then loop through the elements as needed?

```
Dim ArrayTitles() As Variant 'since strings and numbers are mixed
ReDim Preserve ArrayTitles(5)
ArrayTitles(1) = "corp"
ArrayTitles(2) = 1
ArrayTitles(3) = 1
ArrayTitles(4) = 1
ArrayTitles(5) = "TTT"

Range("A2").Select
For i = 1 To 5
MsgBox (ArrayTitles(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking what you are trying to accomplish can be solved in this way

```
for j = 1 to 6 'Or whatever your last column happens to be
    if UCase(cells(1, j)) = "PRODUCT" then
        if ActiveCell.Column = j then
            ActiveCell.Value = "corp"
        end if
    end if
next j
```

Something like that?

Comment: Why not `If UCase(cells(1, ActiveCell.Column)) = "PRODUCT" Then ActiveCell.Value = "corp"`?

Comment: While it's not clear to me what OP wanted, reading between the lines, I believe it's important that it only work when the active cell is right below the header in question.

Comment: After OP's edit it seems clear thar ActiveCell isn't needed here and should be avoided. I just noticed that the loop in your example isn't needed (although it is necessary to solve op's problem) because you can just take the column of activecell instead of looping and checking if you reached that column yet